# can content-available be used in a non-silent push?

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We'd like to send a "regular" push (with an `alert` in `aps`) but with a `content-available` as well.

This way while the user reads the message, we already do some processing and when he taps, the app is ready.

The documentation at

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

is a bit confusing in that regard. Would it work? I've only used them separately in the past (either only `alert`/`sound`/`badge` or `content-available`).

Comment: The documentation is confusing, so this is pure assumption, hence comment. I believe that 
- application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: is called no matter what the content of the payload is. I also have a hazy memory that if a non silent push is received this method is called to give you time to download the data to give a better user experience. Possibly WWDC 2013 talk on background modes

Answer (score 0):

In case any one who finds this is wondering, i have tested, and with ios `9.1`-`10.2`: in order to do background processing, `alert`/`sound`/`badge` is insufficient and you **must** add `content-available`.